# What is memory bank width?

Tags: memory

Ubuntu 16.04, `sudo lshw -class memory` command outputs 4 memory modules with different **width** property:

```
  *-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 19
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 8GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: DIMM 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
      physical id: 0
      slot: A0
      size: 2GiB
      width: 2244 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: DIMM 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
      physical id: 1
      slot: A1
      size: 2GiB
      width: 2244 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:2
      description: DIMM 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
      physical id: 2
      slot: A2
      size: 2GiB
      width: 130 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
 *-bank:3
      description: DIMM 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
      physical id: 3
      slot: A3
      size: 2GiB
      width: 130 bits
      clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
```

What does **width** mean? Why it differs so much? Modules 2,3 are from a different vendor than 0,1.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bandwidth

Comment: @MichaelBay hm, couldn't find an answer there

Comment: Why not? It explains exactly what memory bandwidth is and they're different because the modules are different. For more informations contact the manufacturers.

Comment: @MichaelBay So you're saying the "width" from `lshw` is short for the memory's bandwidth? So here when it says `width: 130 bits` it means the bandwidth is 130 bits/second? Or 16.25 bytes/second? Seems slow, even the other 2244=280 bytes/second. Maybe it's in Mbps or something (I don't really know either, but it sounds reasonable, you'd think they'd flesh out the man page with a little more info)

Comment: Yes, "width" is short for "bandwidth".

Comment: @MichaelBay how you can be sure "width" is short for "bandwidth"?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, my systems (tested on 3 computers) show "width: 64 bits", which matches the data bus width for DDR3 and DDR4.

Comment: @pim really weird indeed. Supposed to be 32 or 64... or at most 128 for video card memory

Comment: No, "width" is not short for "bandwidth". If it were then the units would not be in "bits", but rather Mbit/s (megabits per second) or similar. 
For DDR3 and DDR4 it should be 64 bits - or 72 bits if you have ECC RAM.